# Copying cmd line arguments into an array

Tags: c, arrays, cmd, arguments, line

I'm trying to copy a command line argument into an array in C. 
For example, if I entered `./rpd 5 6 3` then I'd have an array of `{5, 6, 3}`.

My code is:

```
int main(int argc) {

    int numberInQueue;
    char *queueOfClients;
    int i;

    queueOfClients = malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc);

    for(i = 0; i <= argc; i++) {
        queueOfClients[i] = malloc(strlen(*(argc + i)) * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

The error I seem to be getting is:

`error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')`

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: what you are trying is totally unneeded. the arguments are already in an array... starting with your own executable argv[0].

Answer (score 2):

`argc` is the *count* or number of arguments that were handed to your program.

You'll need to parse the actual arguments from the double pointer `argv`.
You do first need to list `argv` as input, though:

```
 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

For an example, check out this page.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/

Answer (score 2):

C comes with this array by default. Your main() should look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
}
```

`argv` is exactly what you want: an array of pointers to character strings. `argc` is just the number of arguments.